# how to resize and subtract numpy arrays in c++

Tags: numpy, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I have two numpy 3D-array in python with different height and width. I want to pass them to my C-Extension. How can I resize and subtract them in c++? Please see the comments in the code.

```
static PyObject *my_func(PyObject *self, PyObject     *args)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();


    PyObject *arr1;
    PyObject *arr2;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &arr1, &arr2)) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //How can I do this?

    //resize arr1 to [100, 100, 3]
    //resize arr2 to [100, 100, 3]
    //res = arr1 - arr2
    //return res
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this in a extension module? That's straight-forward to do with pure python and it's likely as fast (probably only a few microseconds slower).

Comment: Unrelated, but if you really want to push extending your code with C++ I'd consider a wrapper language. They are much easier and robust. Consider for example Cython, ctypes, swig, or my latest favorite: pybind11

Comment: @MSeifert My real problem is not exactly the same as this, but the most important part of the solution is how to resize and subtract numpy array in python. I know this is easy in python.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Thank you for your answer but it is not releated! My question is abvious.I want to do this with python c api not Cyton, ctype, boost, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by making the desired shape. It's easier to do this as a tuple than a list:

```
PyObject* shape = Py_BuildValue("iii",100,100,3);
```

Check this against NULL to ensure do error has occurred and handle if it has.

You can call the [numpy `resize` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) on both arrays to resize them. Unless you are certain that the data isn't shared then you need to call `numpy.resize` rather than the `.resize` method of the arrays. This involves importing the module and getting the resize attribute:

```
PyObject* np = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");
PyObject* resize = PyObject_GetAttrString(np,"resize");
PyObject* resize_result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(resize,arr1, shape,NULL);
```

I've omitted all the error checking, which you should do after each stage.

Make sure you decrease the reference counts on the various `PyObject`s once  you don't need them any more.

Use [`PyNumber_Subtract`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Subtract) to do the subtraction (do it on the result from `resize`).

---

*Addition:* A shortcut for calling resize that should avoid most of the intermediates:

```
 PyObject* np = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");
 // error check against null
 PyObject* resize_result = PyObject_CallMethod(np,"resize","O(iii)",arr1,100,100,3);
```

(The `"(iii)"` creates the shape tuple rather than needing to do it separately.)

---

If you are certain that `arr1` and `arr2` are the only owners of the data then you can call the [numpy `.resize` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) either by the normal C API function calls or the specific numpy function [`PyArray_Resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_Resize).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. PyNumber_Subtract worked but resize didn't. Is this for Python3? or Python2?

Comment: PyObject* res = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(3, dims, NPY_UINT8, FreeImage_GetBits(dib));
PyObject* shape = Py_BuildValue("iii",100,100,3);
PyObject* tmp1 = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(res,"resize",shape, NULL);
it gives compile error. "error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘PyObject*"

Comment: When I change "resize" to "Py_BuildValue("s","resize")" code compiled successfully but gives error in python: "ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data"

Comment: How can I solve this? and second question, may you give me a snippet for PyArray_Resize function? I couldn't use it because it requests PyArrayObject instead of  PyObject. casting with (PyArrayObject)obj not working.

Comment: I've fixed the resize code hopefully. You need to call `numpy.resize` rather than `arr1.resize` because the array doesn't seem to be the sole owner of the data. `PyArray_Resize` would run into the same problem. In general though, you'd check that the object is an array with `PyArray_Check` and then cast to the pointer `(PyArrayObject*)obj`.